# How to evaluate $-\pi \sin(\pi)+\cos(\pi)$ without a calculator?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Hi I'm doing derivatives of trigonometric functions. I needed to find the value of the derivative at $$x=\pi,$$ where $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -x\sin x +\cos x.$$ I found that this was -1 using the calculator, however is this possible to do without a calculator? How does the calculator evaluate this?

I haven't studied advanced trig as of yet.

Thanks

Comment: You know that $\sin \pi=0$, right? And that $\cos\pi=-1$?

Comment: Frankly, if you don't know $\sin\pi$ and $\cos\pi$ without using a calculator, studying derivatives feels kinda pointless.

Comment: @HenningMakholm i didn't think of that, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $\sin\pi = 0$ and $\cos\pi = -1$,
$$-x\sin x + \cos x = -\pi \sin \pi + \cos\pi = -\pi\cdot 0 + (-1) = -1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the unit circle approach, since $\pi$ (radians), which is equivalent to $180^{\circ}$, terminates at the point $(-1,0)$, it follows that $\sin\pi = 0$ and $\cos\pi = -1$. Hence,

$$-\pi\sin\pi + \cos\pi = -\pi(0) + (-1) = -1.$$